# What does a colored dot in the Explorer View in VS Code mean?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am unsure why my file is appearing in red font. Here is what it looks like: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWnoM.png)

Whenever I am trying to run a program, the program runs successfully, still it showing red font in explorer.

Comment: Look at the `Problems` tab.

Comment: if the file contains an error or warning it is colored according to theme colors and so is the parent folder in the explorer

Comment: You can see on the red file that the sumary (top-right) show a red line. Go there to figure out your problem.

Comment: That means there are errors or warnings etc. in the script file. Open the red files, find the errors, and fix them.

Answer (score 2):

The red dot in the explorer tab is called a problem decoration. See also the related `problems.decorations.enabled` setting. The red colour is typically  for error-level problems (yellow typically for warning-level, blue typically for info-level, but it can vary based on your colour theme).

Taking a look at your screenshot, you have a whole heck-ton of problems in your source code (113 errors, 5 warnings).

To get rid of the problem decorations, I'd suggest to actually fix those problems. Open up those files and you'll see red squiggly underlines where the problems are, and hover over them to see what the problem is, and then fix the described problem.

You can view an overview of all problems in the Problems Panel, which you can open with the `View: Toggle Problems` command in the command palette, or `View > Problems` in the menu bar.

The fact that you can run your program successfully probably means that you just haven't yet properly configured IntelliSense in your project. It's impossible to know what you're missing without more info. It might help you to read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java.

<sup>A really stupid and bad way to get rid of those decorations in the Explorer View is to put `"problems.decorations.enabled": false` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). I don't recommend that. Fix the problems.</sup>